# undefined index/values in Jquery Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I create a column in mysql and I set default values like here https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UthB.png 
But when I try to display data on *Extra* column I have a undefined values inside my jquery-flexigrid table:

[image]

I suppose that is an error from my code of 
*index.php* http://pastebin.com/TgAZEZbF
*post2.php* http://pastebin.com/08YHgHri
-----------------------------------
**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flexigrid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexigrid.css" />

<script src="dist/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flexigrid.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#flex1").flexigrid
                        (
                        {
                        url: 'post2.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        colModel : [
                                {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                                {display: 'ISO', name : 'iso', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                                {display: 'Name', name : 'name', width : 300, sortable : true, align: 'left'},

                                {display: 'Printable Name', name : 'printable_name', width : 90, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                                {display: 'ISO3', name : 'iso3', width : 130, sortable : true, align: 'center', hide: false},
                                {display: 'Number Code', name : 'numcode', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                                {display: 'Extra', name : 'extra', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'center', hide: true}
                                ],
                        buttons : [
                                {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : test},
                                {name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : test},
                                {separator: true},
                                {name: 'Anime', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Ebook', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Film', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Giochi PC', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Xbox360', onpress: sortAlpha},

                                {name: 'PS3', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Software', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Musica', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Teatro', onpress: sortAlpha},

                                {name: '5', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'A', onpress: sortAlpha},
                {name: 'B', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'C', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'D', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'E', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'F', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'G', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'H', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'I', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'J', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'K', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'L', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'M', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'N', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'O', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'P', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Q', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'R', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'S', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'T', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'U', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'V', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'W', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'X', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Y', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'Z', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: '#', onpress: sortAlpha},
                                {name: 'あ', onpress: sortAlpha}




                                ],
                        searchitems : [
                                {display: 'ISO', name : 'iso'},
                                {display: 'ISO3', name : 'iso3'},
                                {display: 'Printable Name', name : 'printable_name'},
                                {display: 'Number Code', name : 'numcode'},
                                {display: 'Name', name : 'name', isdefault: true}

                                ],
                        sortname: "id",
                        sortorder: "asc",
                        usepager: true,
                        title: 'Motore di Ricerca',
                        useRp: true,
                        rp: 15,
                        showTableToggleBtn: true,
                        width: 900,
                        height: 355
                        }
                        );  

});
function sortAlpha(com)
                        {
                        jQuery('#flex1').flexOptions({newp:1, params:[{name:'letter_pressed', value: com},{name:'qtype',value:$('select[name=qtype]').val()}]});
                        jQuery("#flex1").flexReload();
                        }

function test(com,grid)
{
    if (com=='Delete')
        {
           if($('.trSelected',grid).length>0){
                   if(confirm('Delete ' + $('.trSelected',grid).length + ' items?')){
            var items = $('.trSelected',grid);
            var itemlist ='';
                for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                                itemlist+= items[i].id.substr(3)+",";
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           url: "delete.php",
                           data: "items="+itemlist,
                           success: function(data){
                                alert("Query: "+data.query+" - Total affected rows: "+data.total);
                           $("#flex1").flexReload();
                           }
                         });
                        }
                        } else {
                                return false;
                        }
        }
    else if (com=='Add')
        {
            alert('Add New Item Action');

        }            
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="flex1" style="display:none"></table>
<br /><br />

</body>
</html>
```

**post2.php**

```
<?
error_reporting(0);
function runSQL($rsql) {
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname   = "country";
        $connect = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
        mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect);
        $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $result = mysql_query($rsql) or die ('test');
        return $result;
        mysql_close($connect);
}

function countRec($fname,$tname,$where) {
$sql = "SELECT count($fname) FROM $tname $where";
$result = runSQL($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
return $row[0];
}
}
$page = $_POST['page'];
$rp = $_POST['rp'];
$sortname = $_POST['sortname'];
$sortorder = $_POST['sortorder'];

if (!$sortname) $sortname = 'name';
if (!$sortorder) $sortorder = 'desc';
                if($_POST['query']!=''){
                        $where = "WHERE `".$_POST['qtype']."` LIKE '%".$_POST['query']."%' ";
                } else {
                        $where ='';
                }
                if($_POST['letter_pressed']!=''){
                        $where = "WHERE `".$_POST['qtype']."` LIKE '".$_POST['letter_pressed']."%' ";  
                }
                if($_POST['letter_pressed']=='#'){
                        $where = "WHERE `".$_POST['qtype']."` REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' ";
                }
$sort = "ORDER BY $sortname $sortorder";

if (!$page) $page = 1;
if (!$rp) $rp = 10;

$start = (($page-1) * $rp);

$limit = "LIMIT $start, $rp";

$sql = "SELECT id,iso,name,printable_name,iso3,numcode,extra FROM country $where $sort $limit";
$result = runSQL($sql);

$total = countRec('iso','country',$where);

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
header("Content-type: text/x-json");
$json = "";
$json .= "{\n";
$json .= "page: $page,\n";
$json .= "total: $total,\n";
$json .= "rows: [";
$rc = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($rc) $json .= ",";
$json .= "\n{";
$json .= "id:'".$row['id']."',";
$json .= "cell:['".$row['id']."','".$row['iso']."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['name'])."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['printable_name'])."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['iso3'])."'";
$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['numcode'])."']";

$json .= "}";
$rc = true;
}
$json .= "]\n";
$json .= "}";
echo $json;
?>
```

I don t understand which error is it and I do not know on that line is the error code.

Comment: paste your code into your post

Comment: seems like data property `extra` is undefined. What does data look like?

Comment: code pasted now, problem is this: if I insert `charlietfl` in mysql value `charlietfl` appears inside mysql table but on jquery table I display `undefined`  and I don't undertand why

Answer (score 0):

Don't manually create json, it is time consuming and error prone.

use `json_encode($array)` instead.

You missed adding a property `extra` in your php for each row so the table plugin is telling you that that field is undefined.

You should be able to see this also by inspecting the data as json in your browser console network tab

Comment: can you repaste my code correctly, please? I am newbie on code and I don't undertand well json-php-mysql mechanism.

Comment: try adding `$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['extra'])."'";`

Comment: After add this piece of code my jquery table says "Processing, please wait" and all values disappears from table. Look: http://i.imgur.com/OMr1eG8.png. I insert this piece of code after `$json .= ",'".addslashes($row['numcode'])."']";` if I insert before change position of data in my column table http://i.imgur.com/F23LUdz.png For example I add **giga** for extra column inside mysql. while **View** values is set for Number Code. But adding this code I move data position in wrong columns

Comment: any idea, charlietfl?